# Full list of objects not showing up after using Zonal Statistics as Table tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I am using the Zonal Statistics as Table tool in ArcMap 10.1 to compute the sum of raster cell values (brown scale in below image) in a given set of polygons (red in below image).

[image: Image of what the data looks like]

For an unknown reason, the output table is not including all the levels of the polygon file I am trying to get information about. I tried on a smaller set of polygons (as these polygons are buffers) and did not have the same problem. I have indeed asked the Zonal Statistics tool to ignore 'Nodata' (as shown in blue), so I am not sure why this is happening. 
Suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean by "the output table is not including all the levels of the polygon file"?

Comment: If buffers overlap Zonal Statistics is not going to work at all, because ArcGIS converts polygons to raster first. Search this site for Zonal Statistics with overlaps, e.g http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141758/using-zonal-statistics-as-table-for-overlapping-polygons-in-arcpy/141773#141773

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) tool does not support overlapping features. This may seem like a bug, but it's a symptom of the fact that Spatial Analyst rasterizes the any vector zone data before processing. Even without overlapping rasters, I tend to run [Polygon to Raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/polygon-to-raster.htm) myself ahead of time so I can better control cell sizes and snap rasters of the zone data.

Fortunately for you, there is an easy workaround! The [**Spatial Analyst Supplemental Tools**](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3528bd72847c439f88190a137a1d0e67), created by Esri, includes something called *Zonal Statistics As Table 2*. As described in the [blog post](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/11/26/new-spatial-analyst-supplemental-tools-v1-3/):

> The Zonal Statistics as Table 2 tool calculates statistics using the values of a raster within zones and reports the results to a table.  This new version offers an improvement over the original Zonal Statistics as Table  geoprocessing tool by **fully handling overlapping polygons** in feature zone input.

You should be able to use this toolbox to perform your desired analysis. I haven't used that toolbox in a year or two, so please report back if you have any compatibility issues with Arc 10.3 or 10.4.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the quick response.  This worked great on my version of ArcMap 10.1. Having read the recent comments on the link you provided me with (http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3528bd72847c439f88190a137a1d0e67) the only thing I'm worried about is if this tool actually calculating all pixels within the polygons or only a portion of them.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Dalal_EL_Hanna If you want confirm, do a spot check compare the results of a few non-overlappping polygons with the regular Zonal Statistics as Table tool to what you get from the supplemental tools.

Comment: I re created my series of buffers using the <Multiple Ring Buffer> tool as to get all my buffers into the same file.  Then, I attempted to use the Zonal Statistics As Table 2 tool to get information on the polygon file with multiple buffers a few times, and everytime, the output does not include all of the objects. Any ideas why this is happenning? I dont think its strictly an overlap problem, as the yielded results (objects it gets results for) are different from the regular Zonal Statistics tool.

Comment: The Zonal Statistics as Table 2 tool is unfortunately not working.  A recent comment on the arc blog (http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3528bd72847c439f88190a137a1d0e67) suggests to edit the Python Code, thoughts on this?